# Message: Class 'PublicKeyLoader' not found (phpseclib)

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I am trying to connect SSH to EC2 server with privatekey using php (phpseclib). I've downloaded phpseclib from GitHub and added into libraries folder.

My code:

```
/* $dir --- contains my library folder path */
include($dir.'phpseclib3/Net/SSH2.php');
include($dir.'phpseclib3/Crypt/PublicKeyLoader.php');
$key = new PublicKeyLoader();
$key->loadPrivateKey(file_get_contents($ppkpath));

$ssh = new SSH2('ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com');
if (!$ssh->login('ec2-user', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```

while executing this I got the following error

> Class 'PublicKeyLoader' not found

Answer (score 4):

You don't load the namespace.

```
$key = new phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader();
```

Better would it be if you installed it with composer is that you include the composer autoloader.

```
include_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

And then load the class in your current namespace with the use statement.

```
use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;
```

That way your code would become:

```php
include_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;
use phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;

$key = new PublicKeyLoader();
$key->loadPrivateKey(file_get_contents($ppkpath));

$ssh = new SSH2('ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com');
if (!$ssh->login('ec2-user', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried as you told. Now I am getting this error **Cannot instantiate abstract class phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader**

Comment: You're supposed to call PublicKeyLoader by doing `$key = PublicKeyLoader::loadPrivateKey(file_get_contents($ppkpath));`. Could do `$key = PublicKeyLoader::load(file_get_contents($ppkpath));` as well

Answer (score 2):

I tried as @Tschallacka said. It works fine. But slightly I rechange the code as follows.

```
include_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;
use phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;

$key = PublicKeyLoader::load(file_get_contents($ppkpath));

$ssh = new SSH2('ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com');
if (!$ssh->login('ec2-user', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```