# How to add entry to /etc/fstab file using php

Tags: php, fstab

Is there any way for add entry to /etc/fstab using php? I have done `lvcreate` and mount each volume into mountfolder using php.

The last step is to edit the mount options in the /etc/fstab file so that the new mount persists after reboot. No documents found for this step using php code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I have create logical volume and mount into '/mntfolder'. No errors and those are successfully done in my ec2-server. I want to do this final step using php. @brombeer

Comment: Under default settings, /etc/fstab is only writable by its owner --- which is **root**

Comment: Try to source a second file inside fstab, check the rights and you can try to use php exec

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. Yes, we can use ssh vi code editor using phpseclib. [Refer my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71437308/message-class-publickeyloader-not-found-phpseclib/71437843#71437843) to connect ssh using phpseclib.

Then my code to write vi /etc/fstab as follows:

```
    $ssh->setTimeout(2);
    $ssh->read();
    //enter vi editor
    $ssh->write("sudo vi /etc/fstab\n");
    $ssh->read();
    //Insert line in vi editor
    $ssh->write("i");
    //enter in new word on that empty line
    $ssh->write("/dev/mapper/uservolumegroup-foldername  /var/www/html/efsmount/foldername   xfs     defaults,nofail   0   0\n");
    //hit escape button
    $ssh->write("\x1B");
    //saves and closes the vi editor
    $ssh->write(":wq!\n");
```